# store and view image blob html.fromhtml android

Tags: android, blob, ormlite

I am trying to show a image saved as blob in my DB. I am using ORMLite and Android 1.6.
I created a textView who show a 'html.FromHtml'

Here is the code:

```
//Save the image in DB.
    ...
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/images/imagem.png");
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    glossary.setImageBytes(byteArray);
```

'glossary' is an instance of Glossary. Who has the field 'imageBytes':

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY)  
private byte[] imageBytes;
```

In my activity I pass this 'imageBytes' to string to use 'html.FromHtml':

```
//Activity
...
String htmlContent = "<h1> Title </h1> 
                      <img src=\""+glossary.getImageBytes.toString()+"\" />"
```

Now in my Adapter I try to show the content of 'htmlContent':

```
//Adapter
...
holder.tvContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlContent, new Html.ImageGetter() {
            @Override
            public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {  
                    byte[] data;
                    data = source.getBytes();
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                    //Log.i("bitmap", "bitmap height:" + String.valueOf(bitmap.getHeight) );
                    //THIS LOG RETURN NPE
                    Drawable d = null;  
                    d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
                    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                    return d;   
                }
            }, null));
...
```

I think the problem is when I change byte to string and string to byte. Because the bitmap created by 'BitmapFactory.decodeFile()' is returning a NPE.

But I don't know how fix that.

Any suggestions?
thx!

Answer (score 0):

Well certainly your first problem is that you should not be doing:

```
glossary.getImageBytes().toString()
```

To turn a `byte[]` into a `String` you should do:

```
new String(glossary.getImageBytes())
```

If you do a `byte[].toString()` it will be set to something like:

```
[B@3487a5cc
```

Instead of a `String` made up of the bytes in the array.

That said, I'm not sure you can just put the bytes from a `PNG` file into a `byte[]` array to be printing out as a `String`.  That sounds like you are going to be printing binary information in your HTML which I don't think will convert correctly.  Also, it looks like you are putting the `PNG` bytes into the `src="..."` HTML section.  That won't work either AFAIK.

Comment: Hmm. Ok, i changed. But the 'bitmap.getHeight' still return a NPE. If I comment him, the display show a byte code.

Comment: @Munir Can you debug your program and make sure that you get the same `byte[]` out from that process that you put in?  I suspect that you are not.

Comment: The `getDrawable(String source)` method process the content of `src` in my tag `<img>`. If I pass a path from him and create a bitmap from this path I got the image in display(I did this test). So I guess the `byte[]` of `src` inside activity is the same of `source` of `getDrawable(String source)`. Sorry for the english.